# What is the best option between buying, building from scratch or implementing an open source ERP?

Tags: php, open-source, erp

I was required to do a medium ERP with the inventory, Bill of Materials, and production modules. However, I do not know how long it would take me.

I am calculating three months for the analysis and lifting of requirements, and 3 months per module. It is a company that manufactures cardboard boxes.

However, I don't know if it would actually be something feasible, or I'm also considering the option of an open source ERP that is in PHP.

What is your opinion?

Thank you very much in advance. Good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parallel to the requirements collection and analysis, I would gather a list of open source ERP solutions (and possibly even commercial ones for comparison) and build a feature matrix.

A system that already supports most of the requirements might allow you to focus on customizing to meet the client's (or employer's) needs and might be ultimately more cost-effective.

I wouldn't be too fixated on an implementation language such as PHP. Of course it should be something that you or your team can handle, and it should be supported in your infrastructure, but code written in Python, Java, JS, Ruby, Go or Rust possibly with Angular, Vue, or React frontends should not be ruled out from the beginning.

Even if the final decision is to write the software from scratch, looking at what existing software provides might be useful.

Comment: Yes, PHP is because of the knowledge of the team. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: About commercial ERP, I need to compare the costs of the different options. And if that were the case, what would my role be. Thanks again.

Comment: I was researching about dolibarr open sourced PHP Erp.